# HAML Having Multiple Lines While Using content_for, for JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, haml, content-for

I am trying to output some inline js on a page. I don't really want to add it to any JS file since it is so aribtrary and one time use. That being said, I am using haml and also trying to use content_for in order to place the JS after jquery is loaded from the layout.

The problem is that haml does not like multiline text that is indented (I think)

I am trying to do the following:

```
=content_for :javascript do
  $(function(){
    $("#sell_tickets_here").live("vclick",function(){
      if($(this).is("checked"))
        $("#tickets_here").display("inline");
      else
        $("#tickets_here").display("none");
    });
  });
```

In my layout I have:

```
  = yield(:javascript)
```

Which actually works if I only have 1 line after the content_for statement.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The correct syntax would be:

```
- content_for :javascript do
  :javascript
    $(function(){
      $("#sell_tickets_here").live("vclick",function(){
        if($(this).is("checked"))
          $("#tickets_here").display("inline");
        else
          $("#tickets_here").display("none");
      }); 
    });
```

Notice the dash versus the equal sign and the `:javascript` [HAML filter](http://haml-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.HAML_REFERENCE.html#javascript-filter).  HAML works just fine with multi-line as long as it is 2-space indented.

And then in the other part of your view:

```
= content_for(:javascript)
```

Comment: Thanks this worked. The only thing to note is that if you have content for javascript coming from multiple pages it'll put in a script tag for each of them. the haml :javascript wraps <script><[cdata around the code. It works for me. For now anyways! Just making a note. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

This is called [escaping](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#escaping_), and in this case you escape, ergh, indentation:

`=content_for :javascript do
  / $(function(){
  /   $("#sell_tickets_here").live("vclick",function(){
  /     if($(this).is("checked"))
  /       $("#tickets_here").display("inline");
  /     else
  /       $("#tickets_here").display("none");
  /   });
  / });`